# Is it possible to define a depency to another application/manifest in a kubernetes manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

i'm deploying an api application with k3s and i would to know if is it possible  to define a depency to another application (potentially already run with is own manifest) in a kubernetes manifest of an application.

If the dependency isn't running when the dependend application is launched, the dependency should be run through its own manifest
I join a schema below.

Thank you in advance for your answers.
[image]

Comment: What does "depends on" mean?  What should happen to the application pods if the database becomes unavailable; if its health checks start failing, or if it's a single pod and its node is unexpectedly terminated?

Comment: (Is this the same as [Specify Depends on in Kubernetes deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526564/specify-depends-on-in-kubernetes-deployment)?  You seem to have gotten a very similar answer.)

Comment: No, this isn't easily possible, and the answers below (and other comments) haven't read the question right. For other readers, the key requirement here is that the required service is automatically started if its missing when either of the dependent services start up.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage dependencies by using the initContainers in your Application 1 and Application 3 and readinessProbe and livenessProbe in your Application 2.

The initContainers in your Application 1 and 3 will check whether the Application 2 is live and the readinessProbe and livenessProbe in your Application 2 will ensure that your Application 2 is fully up and ready to serve.

> Init Container: Init containers solve challenges associated with first-run initialization of applications. It’s common for services to depend on the successful completion of a setup script before they can fully start up.
>
> Liveness probe: This probe is mainly used to determine if the
> container is in the Running state. For example, it can detect service
> deadlocks, slow responses, and other situations.
>
> Readiness probe: This probe is mainly used to determine if the service
> is already working normally. Readiness probes cannot be used in init
> containers. If the pod restarts, all of its init containers must be
> run again.

Reference: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/kubernetes-demystified-solving-service-dependencies_594110